# What is the order of execution of Mason blocks in a component

Tags: perl, mason

What will be the sequence of execution if these blocks are present in a Mason component?

- `%args`
- `%init`
- `%once`
- `%shared`
- `%attr`
- `%flags`

Comment: Feel free to make a test template, run it and see compiled in the code cache. I've done it when made plugin for it. But not remember now :) Here is hierarchy: https://github.com/Camelcade/Perl5-IDEA/issues/905

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. Just wanted to know about %attr. Where does %attr fit in that hierarchy?

Comment: Thanks let me figure out with the method you have mentioned.

Comment: @AlexandrEvstigneev: If you have a reference that helps then you should post it and explain it. I'm not at all sure that the page that you have linked is supposed to represent a hierarchy

Comment: @Borodin I've offered a method how to see the sequence. I've provided link to the data i've done when solved the similar problem. In other words: i've shared my experience in amount and manner I can afford now. And It's better than do nothing.

Comment: @AlexandrEvstigneev: Throwing up a link that you think may help or may be completely wrong isn't better than doing nothing. And you may not realise it, but *"Feel free to make a test template"* implies that you have the authority to prevent thew OP from doing just that, which you don't

Comment: @Borodin I respectefully disagree about doing someting and doing nothing. And yes, my English is bad, sorry :(

Comment: @Borodin and according to "how to answer" manual: Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two different kinds of blocks in that list. "Executable" blocks, which contain executable perl code, and non-executable blocks, which contain key-value pairs (not unlike perl hashes).

## Executable Blocks

**<%once>**

> This block is executed whenever the component is loaded into memory.
> It is executed before any other block.

**<%shared>**

> This block is executed once per request. It is executed before the <%init> block.

**<%init>**

> This block is executed every time the component is called. It is executed  before any other code except for code in <%once> or <%shared> blocks.

## Non-Executable Blocks

**<%args>**

> This block is used to declare the arguments that a component expects.
> In addition, it can also be used to specify a default value if none is
> given when the component is called.

**<%flags>**

> This block is used to declare special Mason flags, which are used to
> affect the component's behavior. Currently, there is only one flag
> defined, `inherit`.

**<%attr>**

> This block is used to declare arbitrary key-value pairs. Unlike the
> <%flags> block, the contents are not used by Mason but may be used in
> your code.

For more information, see the [Mason book](http://masonbook.houseabsolute.com/), from which some of the above was copied (and modified) from.